# Verify APIGW is Caching Lambda Authorizer Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am currently running an API through APIGW, the endpoints are protected by a Lambda Authorizer. In order to improve performance, I enabled caching in APIGW for the Policy generated by the Authorizer.

But, I'm unsure how to effectively test if the cache is working properly. Is there some standard series of calls I could use, or some way to definitively check that the Policy is being cached?

Part of SAM Template:

```yaml
      EndpointConfiguration: 
        Type: PRIVATE
        VPCEndpointIds: !Ref VPCEndpoints
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: DefAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          DefAuthorizer:
            FunctionPayloadType: TOKEN 
            FunctionInvokeRole: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/RoleName
            FunctionArn: !ImportValue AuthorizerArn
            Identity:
              Headers:
                - Authorization
              ReauthorizeEvery: 3600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check two things:

1. Custom Authorizer Lambda will not be invoked at all when it is using the policy from cache.
2. You can enable Api Gateway Stage Logs to cloudwatch. you will see difference in logging.
   When it is cached, you will see only one entry **Using valid authorizer policy for principal**

When it is not cached, you should see additional entires

- Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda....
- Authorizer result body before parsing: ... full policy that was returned by lambda